# Laravel Blade : Not all properties go through to certain mini-views using @yield

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, yield

I am working with Laravel and created a master.blade view file to use on all my pages.
The master view yields mini-views inside.
On most mini-views everything works fine, but on some, I don't get the background image from the master.
The problem is I still get the nav-bar and the footer on those pages, which means they do recognize the master view.
What can be the reason for that?

On all pages I use the exact same way to include and to yield:

@extends('master')

@section('content')

@endsection

Thanks alot!

Comment: If your master has yield section mini-views then you should write @section('mini-views')

Comment: If you are accessing your images by ('../') just do them like so ('/') I had the same problem before

Comment: The master file yields ('content'). I called them 'mini-views' to explain the situation.

Comment: I am accessing the image using: url('images/bgimg.jpg'). Should it also be a problem?
The background image shows up in most pages, but not on all..

Answer (score 0):

Just use full path to your file, start with /

Comment: Even if some pages do show the image? If I use a full path, I will have to change it when the site goes on the web.

Comment: Not - just use 
    url('/path/to/your/image/bgimg.jpg')
instead
    url('path/to/your/image/bgimg.jpg')

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it actually took out the picture from all pages 'cause it messed up the path